# StringToASCII from scratch failed

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, ascii

I actually tried to make a StringToASCII function from scratch in c#.

I get the input from _myString and this is the code :

```
public void convertToASCII() {
    //A-Z --> 65-90
    //a-z --> 97-122
    //0-9 --> 48-57
    //Space --> 32

    int[] returnString = new int[_myString.Length];
    int iTableau = 0;
    char iAZ = 'A';
    char iaz = 'a';
    char i09 = '0';
    char iSpace = ' ';

    for(int i = 0; i < _myString.Length; i++)
    {
        if(_myString[i] >= 65 && _myString[i] <= 90 || _myString[i] >= 97 && _myString[i] <= 122 || _myString[i] >= 48 && _myString[i] <= 57 || _myString[i] == 32)
        {
            while(iAZ < 90 || iaz < 122 || iaz < 122 || i09 < 57 || _myString[i] == 32)
            {
                if(_myString[i] == iAZ && iAZ >= 'A' && iAZ <= 'Z')
                {
                    returnString[iTableau] = iAZ;
                    iTableau++;
                    iAZ--;
                }
                else
                {
                    iAZ++;
                }
                if(_myString[i] == iaz && iaz >= 'a' && iaz <= 'z')
                {
                    returnString[iTableau] = iaz;
                    iTableau++;
                    iaz--;
                }
                else
                {
                    iaz++;
                }
                if(_myString[i] == i09 && i09 >= '0' && i09 <= '9')
                {
                    returnString[iTableau] = i09;
                    iTableau++;
                    i09--;
                }
                else
                {
                    i09++;
                }
                if(_myString[i] == iSpace)
                {
                    returnString[iTableau] = iSpace;
                    iTableau++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    _myString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < returnString.Length; i++)
    {
        _myString += returnString[i];
    }
}
```

I also tried this kind of function which it works, but i would like to make one who checks only chars from A-Z and a-z and 0-9 and space.

Same thing as the first function, i take the input from a global string variable called "_myString".

```
public void convertToASCII()
{
    string asciiChar;
    string returnString = "";

    foreach (char c in _myString)
    {
        asciiChar= ((int)(c)).ToString();
        returnString += " " + asciiChar;
    }
    _myString = returnString;
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here somewhere?

Comment: What do you mean "only check"? What do you do with characters that fall outside those ranges? Just omit them? Use a replacement character? What's wrong with `Encoding.ASCII`?

Comment: @itsme86 first of all thanks for your fast response, i only want to check if _myString[i] is on those range, then i put them into an array that i reassamble by then end.

Comment: @itsme86 My problem with the Encoding.ASCII is that my programming teacher told me that i don't have to use this function but to create it.

Comment: @Abion47 thanks for the fast response, i'm feel sorry but all questions are asked.

Comment: Can you restructure question so that it has a [mcve] that demonstrates the current, wrong, behavior, and how you want it to behave instead?  Ideally something that could be copy/pasted into a console app and tested?  Your code doesn't compile as-is, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/ANEpTN

Comment: @dbc Here you are : https://dotnetfiddle.net/fXrtW2

Comment: @dbc I don't really have time to parse my question to the stack overflow conditions, i'm sorry.

Comment: @dbc I understand your position btw.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually relatively simple:

```
public string StringToLettersOrNumbersOrSpace(string input)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(input[i]) || input[i] == ' ')
        {
            sb.Append(input[i]);
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

First, you'll want to use `StringBuilder` instead of continuously appending to a string variable. Strings in C# are immutable, meaning that they can't be changed after they've been created, so doing something like `string s1 = "aaa"; s1 += "bbb";` will actually create an entirely new string instead of just adding to the original. `StringBuilder`, on the other hand, is mutable, so you don't need to worry about reallocating a bunch of strings every time you want to concatenate strings (which gets progressively slower and slower as the string gets bigger).

Second, you can use `Char.IsLetterOrDigit` instead of using comparisons. The method takes a `char` as input and returns true if the character is a letter (uppercase or lowercase) or a number. This maps directly to your desired range `a-z`, `A-Z`, and `0-9`. Since you also care about spaces, though, you will have to manually check for that.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cay4xx2f(v=vs.110).aspx - suggesting to use IsLetterOrDigit to detect ASCII letters makes absolutely no sense (also I somewhat support trolling OP with invalid solution - but it does not look like it is your goal).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Did you read the question body? OP's goal is specifically to get letters in the range `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and space characters.

Comment: I don't see any requirement to covert letters and digits - i.e. can you explain how `'Ф'` should be represented in ASCII string (`Char.IsLetterOrDigit('Ф') == true`)?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov `i would like to make one who checks only chars from A-Z and a-z and 0-9 and space.` He says it right there.

Comment: @VetonSadiku I suppose I should ask you for the clarification. What specifically is your goal here?

Comment: Than why *your* function is called `StringToASCII`? I have no idea why OP said that and what they mean - this post is misleading and need to be cleaned up - possibly just renaming function may be an option (also adding some explanation what exactly suggested code is doing would be nice and possibly make post into good SO answer)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thank you for your constructive criticism, but once again, i didn't have time to make a complete and in good form post.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I only named the method that because it's what OP named his method, and that's generally what I do when I answer to make the delivery of the code as an answer more clear. I agree that it's misleading, though.

Comment: @VetonSadiku Then you really should have waited until you did have time. Bad form questions usually get bad answers or no answers, and even potentially closed or put on hold. It ends up being a bit of a waste of time if you have to come back later and rephrase everything anyway.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Better?

Comment: @Abion47 I mean, what steps do i have to do to close my question.

Comment: @VetonSadiku Either choose an answer by clicking on the check mark or delete the question.

Comment: @abion looks much better - thanks, also I'm still find statement about "maps to your desired range" somewhat confusing...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov How so? "Map to a range" isn't that uncommon a term.

Comment: @Abion47 nothing wrong with usage of "map to a range" term... But since OP did not define input range there are 2 real options - all characters already limited to [A-Za-z0-9\s] or all characters are allowed - in former case call to the IsLetterOrDigit is pointless, in later case all other letters/numbers will be passed as-is (and not replaced with placeholder/omitted as one would expect with "to ASCII" conversion).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Until OP decides to clarify what his input is and what he expects the output to be, I feel like my assumption is as good as any.